# How to move html/css content to a different column

Tags: php, html, css

Right now I have this program that echoes out an image and a text ten times. It does so all in one column. I want to make it so that it fills up one whole page by going horizontally after it hits the end of the page in one column. After all the columns fill up, then it can go to the next page. Here is my code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      echo '<div>';
      echo "<p style='font-size:1.05em;color:#0e3c68;font-weight:bold;'>" . $row['question'] . "</p>";
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row['imagename'] .'" height="125" width="125" class="img-thumnail" /> 
      echo '<div>';
```

Comment: Seems that flexbox might be more useful for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information. Are the columns a set width and height? How tall is the container of the columns? Is it static or dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Just your code as following.

```
echo '<div style="text-align: center;display: inline-block;">';
  echo "<p style='font-size:1.05em;color:#0e3c68;font-weight:bold;'>" . $row['question'] . "</p>";
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row['imagename'] .'" height="125" width="125" class="img-thumnail" /> 
  echo '<div>';
```